# After typo3 update - text does not wrap around image, images are not displayed in columns

Tags: typo3

After the typo3 update to version 8.7 I am having an issue with images.

First text is no longer wraping around images although the alignment for the image is set to wrap around the text. See here: http://www.vbl.org

Second images are no longer displayed in columns, although number of columns is set to 5. See here: http://www.vbl.org/berichte/bildberichte-2018/halbziit-2-juni-2018.html

Why is this happening?

Comment: Are images embed with RichTextEditor or by default way with Content Element of type 'Image' / 'Media'?

Comment: are you using CSS_Styled_content or fluid_styled_content?

Comment: CSS_Styled_content. Is this the issue?

Comment: Have you included static template from extension css_styled_content. In TYPO3 8 is a new one: TypoScript Content Elements CSS.

Comment: Adding TypoScript Content Elements CSS fixed it. Do you want to post it as a solution?

Comment: I wrote an answer. Thank you for marking as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TYPO3 8 the extension css_styled_content has a second optional template. Add static template from extension css_styled_content: TypoScript Content Elements CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed some CSS.
In your compressed CSS at least one include (`gray-theme.css`) results in a `404`.

And maybe the markup has changed, so HTML and CSS does not match any longer.